# LINQ creating a new anonymous type when selecting a property that is a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Simple POCO like this:

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof (CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
public class MyType
{

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name;

    [JsonExtensionData(ReadData = true, WriteData = true)]
    public IDictionary<string, object> TypeDetails { get; set; }
}
```

and a method that gives me a list of `MyType`
i'm trying to return a list of `Dictionary<string,object>` with all the TypeDetails of the object list i got. 
like this:

```
types.Select((myType) => myType.TypeDetails)
```

however, when i run this, what i get is a list of Dictionaries, but with the following shape:

```
[
  {TypeDetails: {the dictionary i want},
  {TypeDetails: {the dictionary i want}},
  (...)
]
```

what i was expecting:

```
[
  {the dictionary i want},
  {the dictionary i want},
  (...)
]
```

to clarify: i'd like this to be true:
`types[0].TypeDetails.equals(r[0])`

It's the same as if i were doing

```
types.Select((myType) => new {myType.TypeDetails})
```

if i get any other property the select behaves as i expected it.
i can't find any doc that indicates whether dictionaries get a special treatment, nor any other clue about why this is happening.

Comment: did you try .SelectMany instead of .Select

Comment: What would be wrong with `myType.TypeDetails.Values` instead of `myType.TypeDetails` ?

Comment: I don't understand your issue, `types.Select((myType) => myType.TypeDetails)` yields a `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>` which seems like what you're after? or put it to a list `types.Select((myType) => myType.TypeDetails).ToList()`? please elaborate...

Comment: I was unable to recreate your issue

Comment: How are you performing the serialization? It's unclear how you're going from the Select to the JSON representation and may be relevant.

Comment: @Aominè it gives me a dict. but not the one i want. instead of the dict contained in `TypeDetails` i get a dict with a single key `TypeDetails` and its value is the dict i want. i thought  i was clear with the what i expected part of the question, i'll try to clarify it

Comment: @JonathonChase i'm performing it via asp.net core. but it doesn't seem to be the problem. because watching it from the debugger shows me the same thing.

Comment: welp. @AussieJoe 's comment sent me in the right direction. using `.Values` shielded a collection of collections with the dicts i wanted. so i changed the `Select` to a `SelectMany` and it gave me the correct result. 
the line ended up like this: `types.SelectMany((myType) => myType.TypeDetails.Values)`
@AussieJoe if you want, write that as a response and i'll mark it as the answer

Comment: @Jarry done...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.SelectMany()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) on the Dictionary's *values*, like so:

```
types.SelectMany((myType) => myType.TypeDetails.Values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your return expectation/description is out:

> i'm trying to return a list of `Dictionary<string,Object>`

or, (assuming `(myType)` is of type `MyType`), your real code does not match:

> types.Select((myType) => myType.TypeDetails)

The example code below does return a collection of `Dictionary<string,Object>`, it'd be interesting to see where your code differs from it:

```
var data = new[]
{
    new MyType()
    {
        TypeDetails = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "foo", "bar" } }
    },
    new MyType()
    {
        TypeDetails = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "baz", "qux" } }
    },
};
var r = data.Select(d => d.TypeDetails);
```

Comment: what does that collection have inside?
what happens if you run `data[0].TypeDetails.equals(r[0])`

Comment: `true` - it's the same object

Comment: Just seen your comment - it looks like it was the former of my suggestions - you didn't want a list of Dictionary<string,Object>, you wanted a list of the values contained in the dictionaries.

Comment: yeah, the values and the keys. it's been a while and my C# is apparently rustier than i thought ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.  i'll have to think about this because i'm having trouble parsing through this.